# How to use OpenLayers Geolocate with the OpenGeo Suite Client SDK?

Tags: openlayers-2, web-mapping, gps, boundless-suite, sdk

I’d like to have GPS functionality added to my OpenGeo Suite Client SDK application.

From what I understand it should be possible to use the Geolocate control from OpenLayers.   Preferably there would be a checkbox (placed on map.tbar) with the option of continuous tracking. If that’s not possible, a button that gets the current position would do as well (like this [example](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/geolocation.html)).

How would I go about incorporating Geolocate?

Thanks.

Comment: I found [this](https://github.com/Gnafu/mapstore/commit/85bf78c3d8c41a6d640aa8dd4ad1fad8d6f69c3b), seems to work well.

Answer (score 1):

You would create a custom plugin where the checkbox would be your action. See http://suite.opengeo.org/opengeo-docs/apps/plugincreate/ for a tutorial.

Comment: Thanks, with the help of the github files I linked to and the plugin tutorial I'll probably be able to get something pretty close to what I want.